# Jquery mobile embed youtube videos

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, youtube

I have a jquery mobile app that plays youtube videos. All videos work great on the phone when i test the website, but after i package it for Itunes or google play, some videos don't work, getting the warning:

> "This video contains content from SME..."

Why would the work on the phone when i test the website but not in the app... nothing changes in the code.

This is how i embed them:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).find(".youtube").val() + '?feature=player_detailpage&vq=hd720&showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

"This video contains content from SME..." will be a message from Youtube and not something you'll be able to get around. (SME = Sony Media Entertainment). Likely the video has had copyright restrictions put on it by request of Sony.